# Best way to identify a handful of records expected to have a flag set to TRUE

Tags: oracle

I have a table that I expect to get 7 million records a month on a pretty wide table. A small portion of these records are expected to be flagged as "problem" records.

What is the best way to implement the table to locate these records in an efficient way?

I'm new to Oracle, but is a materialized view an valid option? Are there such things in Oracle such as indexed views or is this potentially really the same thing?

Most of the reporting is by month, so partitioning by month seems like an option, but a "problem" record may be lingering for several months theorectically. Otherwise, the reporting shuold be mostly for the current month. Would you expect that querying across all month partitions to locate any problem record would cause significant performance issues compared to usinga single table?

Your general thoughts of where to start would be appreciated. I realize I need to read up and I'll do that but I wanted to get the community thought first to make sure I read the right stuff.

One more thought: The primary key is a GUID varchar2(36). In order of magnitude, how much of a performance hit would you expect this to be relative to using a NUMBER data type PK? This worries me but it is out of my control.

Comment: Is the intent of marking them as problem records to exclude them from reporting?  Or to work them later?  Also, when you say a small number, do you mean like 1% or .1%?

Comment: do you mean to say that there will be a column on this table with a value set to 'T' and you want to query those efficiently?

Comment: Starting from the simplest possible thing that could work, it seems like an index on the table (potentially a global index in the case of a partitioned table) would be sufficient.  Is there some additional information that leads you to look into more exotic options?

Answer (score 2):

It depends what you mean by "flagged", but it sounds to me like you would benefit from a simple index, function based index, or an indexed virtual column.

- In all cases you should be careful to ensure that all the index columns are NULL for rows that do not need to be flagged. This way your index will contain only the rows that are flagged (Oracle does not - by default - index rows in B-Tree indexes where all index column values are NULL).
- Your primary key being a VARCHAR2 GUID should make no difference, at least with regards to the specific flagging of rows in this question, [indexes will point to rows via Oracle internal ROWIDs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e15858/tgsql_optop.htm#TGSQL228.).
- Indexes support partitioning, so if your data is already partitioned, your index could be set to match.

**Simple column index method**

If you can dictate how the flagging works, or the column already exists, then I would simply add an index to it like so:

```
CREATE INDEX my_table_problems_idx ON my_table (problem_flag)
/
```

**Function-based index method**

If the data model is fixed / there is no flag column, then you can create a function-based index assuming that you have all the information you need in the target table. For example:

```
CREATE INDEX my_table_problems_fnidx ON my_table (
  CASE 
    WHEN amount > 100 THEN 'Y'
    ELSE NULL 
  END
)
/
```

Now if you use the same logic in your SELECT statement, you should find that it uses the index to efficiently match rows.

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE CASE 
  WHEN amount > 100 THEN 'Y'
  ELSE NULL 
END IS NOT NULL
/
```

This is a bit clunky though, and it requires you to use the same logic in queries as the index definition. Not great. You could use a view to mask this, but you're still duplicating logic in at least two places.

**Indexed virtual column**

In my opinion, this is the best way to do it if you are computing the value dynamically (available from 11g onwards):

```
ALTER TABLE my_table
ADD virtual_problem_flag VARCHAR2(1) AS (
  CASE 
    WHEN amount > 100 THEN 'Y'
    ELSE NULL
  END
)
/

CREATE INDEX my_table_problems_idx ON my_table (virtual_problem_flag)
/
```

Now you can just query the virtual column as if it were a real column, i.e.

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE virtual_problem_flag = 'Y'
/
```

This will use the index and puts the function-based logic into a single place.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new table with just the pks of the problem rows.

Comment: That's essentially what an index is. Not sure what you would hope to gain from doing this manually.

Comment: Totally different. The table will only contain as many rows as needed, index mostly redundant. Not affected so much by partition ing. Allows for additional data to be associated with the problem record without cluttering the main record. More "correct" relationally. Excuse terseness, on tablet.

Comment: An index doesn't always contain all rows. As per my answer, it could contain pointers to only the relevant rows. Indexes on partitioned tables also don't have to be partitioned in the same way as their base table, or at all. It doesn't seem more "correct" relationally to me to duplicate data when there are already so many ways of handling this problem.